# getFlashBag() causes Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '256' reached

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

When I start phpUnit test, I get the following error 'Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '256' reached'.

I have checked my code and I found that using Symfony/Session:

`$session = new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session();
$surfbar_warning = $session->getFlashBag()->get('tmp_session_id');`

is causing such problem.

I have increased the Maximum=2000 in php.ini, but it does not help or solve the problem.

Do you have any suggestion how to deal or work around such scenario?

Comment: Why are you using this code?  You are not supposed to create a session object, you must use `$request->getSession()->getFlashBag()` Can you show all the code?

Comment: thank you Stephan for your response. Actually I create such a session bag:

`$session = new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session();

            // set flash messages
            $session->getFlashBag()->add()`

Then I need to read it. when I use  `request->getSession() <==> NULL`

Therefore I create a new instance of Symfony Session.

Comment: Why don't you use $request->getSession()->getFlashBag() ?

Comment: because `$request->getSession()` returns null, and does not store the created Symfony Session.

Comment: Show your controller code please.

Comment: Instead of sharing code in comments, please update the body of your question.